# How to disable a timer job during a certain timeframe?

Tags: 2013, powershell, timer-jobs, schedule, scheduled-tasks

I have a timer job in SharePoint 2013 that needs to run every 5 minutes, but not  during certain timeframes each day. The only way I could find to do this was to use a Windows Scheduled Task to run a Powershell script which runs "Disable-SPTimerJob" and "Enable-SPTimerJob". This seems like fairly basic functionality that should be in SharePoint. Am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That would be the easiest way to do it, and the way I'd recommend you to do it.